# Orca Power Shell

Tags: windows-installer, orca

I am trying to create a transform using Orca so that I can automate the install of an msi file. The problem is I struggling to find out how I automate the clicking of a 'Next' button that would appear in the Wizard. I thought that I needed to create a property name for the 'Next Button' in the 'Controls' table in Orca then add a new row into the 'Property' table in Orca. Then add the value of '1' to the value of the newly craeted property. Bu this didnt work when I generated the transform file and ran the following command line -

msiexec /I "msiName.msi" TRANSFORM="transformName.mst"

Can anybody shed any light?

Answer (score 1):

It's `TRANSFORMS=transformName.mst`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14237187)

Comment: @Wildcat Sorry, if I remember well I didn't have enough "reputation" to comment so I tried to answer the question. If the property TRANSFORMS is misspelled, it will not work.